# I want to create django popup form in my project

Tags: python, django, forms, popup

I have created fee management system in django.

The problem is I am using simple form and for each form user have to navigate to separate page.

I want to create popup form in django. I have search many websites but can't get solution

[image]

In above window when user click on payment button pop-up form will be open.
and when user click on submit button changes will be shown in same page.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this? or share code if you have work in same area.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [Ask] first to understand how SO works and what are good questions. Your current question doesn't show that you've tried anything and doesn't provide a reproducible problem. You should look at how to use javascript and ajax to create in-place views and to call django views. There are also packages that do this for you. Please research more and start coding, then ask questions when you encounter a specific issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Why not use bootstrap modals instead?

For example https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/

Examples
To see django-bootstrap-modal-forms in action clone the repository and run the examples locally:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/trco/django-bootstrap-modal-forms.git
$ cd django-bootstrap-modal-forms
$ python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
$ python manage.py migrate
$ python manage.py runserver
```

Signup form in Bootstrap modal
For explanation how all the parts of the code work together see paragraph Usage. To test the working solution presented here clone and run Examples.
forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from bootstrap_modal_forms.mixins import PopRequestMixin, CreateUpdateAjaxMixin


class CustomUserCreationForm(PopRequestMixin, CreateUpdateAjaxMixin,
                             UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2']
```

signup.html

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Sign up</h3>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">

    <div class="{% if form.non_field_errors %}invalid{% endif %} mb-2">
      {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        {{ error }}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {% for field in form %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
        {% render_field field class="form-control" placeholder=field.label %}
        <div class="{% if field.errors %} invalid{% endif %}">
          {% for error in field.errors %}
            <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="submit-btn btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from bootstrap_modal_forms.mixins import PassRequestMixin
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm

class SignUpView(PassRequestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
    success_message = 'Success: Sign up succeeded. You can now Log in.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup')
]
```

.html file containing modal, trigger element and script instantiating modalForm

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="signup-btn btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button">Sign up</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    // Sign up button
    $(".signup-btn").modalForm({formURL: "{% url 'accounts:signup' %}"});

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. You have solved my problem.

Answer (score 11):

Using popups/modals is best done with frameworks as they provide easy building. Trying to code many modals on a single page manually can be laborious. But if you must, here is a [single popup example](https://codepen.io/broderickdevelopment/pen/KxjGop) i've coded in vanilla html, css and javascript.

The basic principle is:

- The popup is a dimmed `div` which covers 100% of the viewport. It has is display `none`.
- When the button is clicked, the popup div's display property is set to `block`
- The popup div can sit outside of your main site's content. It is able to do this by having `absolute` positioning.

As others have stated, check out some frameworks which provide modals, such as [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo) and [bulma](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/modal/)

```js
var popup1 = document.getElementById("popup-1")
var openPopup1 = document.getElementById("open-popup-1")
var closePopup1 = document.getElementById('close-popup-1')

openPopup1.addEventListener('click', () => {
 popup1.style.display = "block";
})

closePopup1.addEventListener('click', () => {
 popup1.style.display = "none";
})
```

```css
body {
 font-family: arial;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-site {
 padding-top: 5px;
 width: 95%;
 max-width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#popup-1 {
 display: none;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 position: absolute;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
}

.popup-content {
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: white;
 width: 400px;
 top: 5vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup-1">
 <div class="popup-content">
  <h1>Popup Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <button id="close-popup-1">Close</button>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="main-site">
 <h1>Webpage</h1>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
 <button id="open-popup-1">Open Popup</button>
</div>
```